# Ayuda con redirección, PHP Geo + Include

Tags: php, javascript

Ojalá alguien pudiera echarme una mano... Explico: me gustaría seleccionar diferentes archivos según el GEO de la IP del visitante, para esto tengo los archivos index-es.php (Para España) index-lat.php (para Latinoamérica ), index-eur.php (para Europa) and index-usd.php (para todos loa países que no estén en Europa, España o Latinoamerica)

Solamente me funciona el código para Europa y para el resto de países pero el de España y LatinoAmerica no funciona.

Alguien tiene idea de por qué? Adjunto el código

```js
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
preg_match('/geoplugin_countryCode";s:[0-9]+:"(?<country_code>[^"]+)/', $html, $code);
$country = array('ES', 'AL', 'AT', 'AZ', 'BY', 'BE', 'BM', 'BG', 'CZ', 'HR', 'EE', 'DK', 'GE', 'FR','FI', 'DE', 'GR', 'HU', 'IE', 'KZ', 'IT', 'LV', 'LT', 'LU', 'MT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'RO', 'RU', 'SK', 'SI', 'SE', 'CH', 'TR', 'UA', 'KY', 'GI', 'VG', 'GB');

/**
 */
if(in_array($code['country_code'], $country)) { include("pages/index/index-eur.php");
} elseif(in_array($code['country_code'], 'MX', 'CL', 'AR', 'UY', 'PY', 'BO', 'PE', 'EC', 'CO', 'VE', 'PA', 'CR', 'NI', 'HN', 'SV', 'GT', 'RD', 'PR')) { include("pages/index/index-lat.php");
} elseif(in_array($code['country_code'], 'ES')) { include("pages/index/index-es.php");




} else {
    include("pages/index/index-usd.php");  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás utilizando erróneamente la función `in_array()`. Esta necesita al menos dos parámetros: el primero es el valor buscado y el segundo es un array donde lo buscaremos. Como puedes ver, los valores europeos están guardados en un array, sin embargo los latinos y el español no. Este sería el bloque editado:

```
if(in_array($code['country_code'], $country)) { include("pages/index/index-eur.php");
} elseif(in_array($code['country_code'], array('MX', 'CL', 'AR', 'UY', 'PY', 'BO', 'PE', 'EC', 'CO', 'VE', 'PA', 'CR', 'NI', 'HN', 'SV', 'GT', 'RD', 'PR'))) { 
    include("pages/index/index-lat.php");
} elseif($code['country_code'] == 'ES') {
    include("pages/index/index-es.php");
} else {
    include("pages/index/index-usd.php");  
}
```

Al español le quité la función in_array ya que puede tener un único valor

Comment: Hola Matías, muchísimas gracias! Funcionó, te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Podrías marcarla como respuesta correcta? Muchas gracias y me alegro que te haya ayudado :D

Comment: Hola Matías, cómo podría contactar contigo? Quizás te interesaría ayudarme remuneradamente. Saludos!

Comment: Te he agregado en Skype :)